# Как собрать годовую частотность?

Tags: seo

Сервис Яндекс Вордстат позволяет собирать частотности за предыдущий месяц. Подскажите пожалуйста где собрать частотность за год, если запросы сезонные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частоты за год можно снять через Key Collector, но не через вордстат, а через директ. 
http://www.key-collector.ru/usage.php - здесь в пункте "сбор сезонности" можно подробно узнать о сборе сезонных данных (даже с графиком по месяцам).